# Unable to figure out equation with set probabilities

Tags: probability, self-study, subset

I am currently self-studying with Casella & Berger and there is a problem that has me stumped. Please note I am NOT asking for a solution, I just need clarification on the terms used.

Here is the exercise in question:

[image: C&B exercise]

The way I understand the definition of the set Ek, it is not generally true that P(E1) = P(A1) + ...  + P(An).

To illustrate, with A1 = {1,2} and A2 = {1,2,3}, E1 would denote elements contained in exactly one of A1 and A2, namely E1 = {3}. The statement in problem (b) would therefore be equivalent to P({3}) = P({1,2}) + P({1,2,3}).

Comment: "Exactly" in (a) means what it says. Thus $E_1=\{3\}$ and $E_2=\{1,2\}$.  Your example should read $$P\left(\{1,2\}\cup\{1,2,3\}\right)=P(\{3\})+P(\{1,2\}).$$

Comment: One note that might be relevant to the question you attempt to solve (but not necessarily the question you pose here) is that there is an errata sheet (http://www.stat.ufl.edu/archived/casella/class/errata7.pdf) for Casella & Berger and some of the parts of question 1.42 have errors in the text.

Comment: Thank you both for your replies. I have posted an answer based on the information provided, do let me know if this goes against site etiquette.

Comment: @whuber You might have missed that the question is about (b), not (a)!  OP's example seems to indeed be a counterexample against the statement in the original (b)  (when $P(\{1,2\})>0$), and in the errata (b) is replaced with something completely different.

Comment: @Juho I don't believe I missed that at all.  I looked at the errata and would not characterize it as "completely different," but only as a clarification.  The problem with the current question is that it presents an incorrect interpretation of the mathematical notation.

Comment: @whuber Let us assume $n=2$, $A_1=\{1,2\},~A_2=\{1,2,3\}$ (is something already incorrect?). By substituting $k=1$ into "Let $E_k$ denote the set..." we get that $E_1$ is the set containing outcomes that are contained in exactly $1$ of $A_1,A_2$. $1$  and $2$ are  contained in $A_1$ and $A_2$, so 2 sets. $3$ is only in $A_2$, possible other outcomes are in $0$ $A_i$s. Thus we conclude $E_1=\{3\}$. Then, the left hand side of the equation in (b) becomes $P(E_1)=P(\{3\})$. The rhs is $P(A_1)+P(A_2) = \sum_{i=1}^2 P(A_i) = P(A_1)+P(A_2) = P(\{1,2\})+P(\{1,2,3\})$

Comment: @whuber in your first comment you say $E_1=\{3\}$  -  why should the left hand side of the equation, which is $P(E_1)$, then read $P(\{1,2\} \cup \{1,2,3\})$? OP indeed understands $E_1=\{3\}$ as that is written in the question. What $E_2$ is does not matter at all since it does not appear in the claimed equation $P(E_1) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} P(A_i)$.

Comment: @Juho My comment refers to the illustration in the question, which bears on the definition in part (a).

Comment: @whuber The only (relevant) definition I find in (a) is that of  $E_1$, about which your first comment and OP's illustration agree that $E_1=\{3\}$.

Comment: @whuber Let me paraphrase the 'illustration' (I'd call it a counterexample to (b)) in 3 steps A,B,C - which of these is wrong?  A) Let us consider an example where $n=2,~A_1=\{1,2\},~A_2=\{1,2,3\}$. B) Then, per the definition in (a), $E_1=\{3\}$. C) Then, the equation that we are asked to show in (b) -- $P(E_1) = \sum_{i=1}^n P(A_i)$ -- is equivalent to $P(\{3\}) = P(\{1,2\}) + P(\{1,2,3\})$?

Answer (score 1):

Piecing together the replies by whuber and Matt Brems, it seems I did understand question 1.42(b) correctly, it's just that there's a mistake in the book.

(I'm still quite unsure of what proper etiquette mandates on this site but my observations lead me to conclude self-replying with an answer is appropriate)

Comment: Your understanding of the site is correct--but this does not appear to answer your question!  Indeed, upon re-reading your original post I am left wondering what it is you were trying to ask.